# React isn't rendering on 2nd Electron Window

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

This is the error I get inside of the 2nd windows Dev Tools

[image]When I try to open my 2nd window through a button, the page opens correctly but React doesn't Render my Form. Im not sure what I'm doing wrong as it should render it. The HTML for the 2nd window loads properly but react isn't rendering.

My Package.json

```
{
  "name": "electron_react_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "electron-is-dev": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron-dev": "concurrently \"BROWSER=none yarn start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\""
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
    "electron": "^8.1.0",
    "electron-builder": "^22.4.0",
    "wait-on": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "main": "public/electron.js"
}
```

My 2nd Window HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Add Product</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Product-Form">
    </div>

    <script src="../src/indexAdd.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Form React Component (This part is not rendering)

```
import React from 'react'

class AddProductForm extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            itemName : '',
            SKU : '',
            Size : '',
            TotalAmountPaid : '',
            Sold : '',
            PriceSoldFor : '',
            Goat : '',
            Stockx : '',
            FlightClub : '',
        }
        this.formProductHandle = this.formProductHandle.bind(this)
    }
    formProductHandle = () => {

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Product Page Form
                <form>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Product Name'/>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='SKU'/>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Size'/>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Total Amount Paid'/>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Sold'/>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Price Sold For'/>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Goat Link'/>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Stockx Link'/>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AddProductForm
```

My React.Dom File for the form that isn't rendering

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
import AddProductForm from './addProductForm'

window.onload = () => {
    console.log('Worked!')
    ReactDom.render(<AddProductForm />, document.getElementById('Product-Form'))}
```

My Button React Component (This handles and opens 2nd window)

```
import React from 'react'
const electron = window.require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const BrowserWindow = electron.remote.BrowserWindow

class OpenAddProductPage extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {

        }
        this.addProductHandle = this.addProductHandle.bind(this)
    }
    addProductHandle = () => {
        let modalPath = path.join('file://',__dirname, '../public/addProduct.html')
        console.log(modalPath)
        let win = new BrowserWindow({width:400, height:200})
        win.on('close', () => { win = null })
        win.loadFile(modalPath)
        //win.loadFile('./public/addProduct.html')
        win.show()
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button className='Add-Buttons' onClick={this.addProductHandle}>Add Product</button>
                <button className='Add-Buttons' >Delete Product</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default OpenAddProductPage
```